# Can't start new Activity in Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing a game and I need to switch activities when the game is over. My problem is I have a gameLogic Java class which extends to Activity, it is not an main activity class.

So I have a gameover method in GameLogic Class which returns boolean. If it returns false it has to switch to the second Activity but it doesn't. It returns `null.pointer.exception`.

Here is the code:

```
public void gameOver(GameData data){

        if(!intersect(data)){

            Intent intent = new Intent(GameLogic.this , SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
}
```

and I am calling this method in GameData class in OnDraw method because OnDraw Method always has to control if it is gameover or not

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
.........
....
......
.....
............
logic.gameOver(this);

}
```

ERROR:

> 08-20 14:13:58.293 29830-29830/com.example.msimsi.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.example.msimsi.myapplication, PID: 29830
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>
> 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                             at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
>                                                                                             at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:77)
>                                                                                             at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:4160)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.example.msimsi.myapplication.GameLogic.gameOver(GameLogic.java:230)
>                                                                                             at com.example.msimsi.myapplication.GameData.onDraw(GameData.java:86)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15231)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>                                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>                                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: please make sure that your object is not null

Comment: It's not clear what code caused the error because you have not included a [mcve]. Can you please read your stacktrace to identify where your code crashes

Comment: Your stack trace is telling you exactly why you got a NullPointerException...

Comment: @Krease  I am new to android so I dont understand the trace

Comment: I'll make a guess what the -6 downvotes are for: (a) a generally chatty style, including "please help" fluff in the title, (b) an `onDraw` code sample containing nearly all placeholder dots rather than actual code, (c) asking posters for their email address so you can avoid the need to ask a clear question, (d) using the phrase `it doesn't work` rather than supplying useful extra information to helpers so they have something solid to respond to. Hope that helps, happy to explain more if needs be.

Comment: can you share some more code like both class which include you method and your new activity class ?

Answer (score 0):

You need get the application context.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm not an expert.

Comment: Why the application context? The first parameter just needs to be any context

Comment: please help me @cricket_007 do you know how to solve it

Comment: Thank you for this information. Why @Shailesh Limbardiya has the same getApplicationContext()...

Comment: @Initerworker if you just give your mail I can send you the code

Comment: @EMREALP I sent you my mail by linkedin.

Comment: @Initerworker: we can't stop you sharing your contact details, but bear in mind that is not what Stack Overflow is for. Longstanding readers will encourage you to help in public, so other people can benefit from the advice also.